# How to add a line break in Rmarkdown code?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have an rmarkdown document with this:

```
`r {"### MyHeading"}`
```

I would like to add a line break after this (no text, just an empty line).  How can I accomplish this by just editing the existing block of code and not adding another?  i.e. is there something like this:

```
`r {"### MyHeading"}&nbsp;`
```

This fails and says object 'nbsp' not found.

Comment: you can use <br>

Comment: can you show where in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br/>`'s **inside** the Markdown/HTML block:

```
`r {"### MyHeading<br/><br/><br/>"}`
```

[image]

Note that the `&nbsp;` you were adding was outside, not inside the double quotes.

Comment: This works, but when I add the <br> at the beggining: {"## <br/>MyHeading<br/>"} it shows up in the table of contents as a line break, which looks funny.  I just want the line break to be reflected in the actual content of the RMarkdown, and not the table of contents tabs.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the index generator. I think it should stripe out HTML contents. On the other hand you could add the space before the title too. Also, have you tried using `---` to separate sections?